# navigation "position fixed" is not giving the expected result in html

Tags: html, css

i wrote a code for my navigation bar to stay at fixed position using `position: fixed;`so that when anybody tried to scroll the page it stay at their current position but i am not getting the desired result.

here is my navigation bar (without  changing code):-

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

---

but when i add `position: fixed;` in my coding like :-

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

my navigation bar moves to bottom of the page:-

[image]

---

but if i remove `bottom: 0;` from my code:-

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

or

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

in both the cases my navigation bar moves to this position:-

[image]

---

and also i cannot remove `position: absolute;` from my code as it also changes the position of my navigation bar:-

```
#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    right: 0;
}
```

[image]

---

**what i want ?:-**

[image]

---

here is my code:-

```css
header {
    width:100%; 
    height:350px; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-1;
    border:3px solid grey;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
} 

#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#navul01 li {
    float: left;
}

#navul01 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:2px solid white;
}

#navul01 li a:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}


#subjects_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

#subjects_nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:3px solid white;
    transition: 1s;
}

#subjects_nav li a:hover {
    margin: 0 -5%;
}

#physics_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

#chemistry_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

#maths_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

#space {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   </head>

   <body> 
      <div class="main-wrapper"> 
         <header> </header> 
         <div><nav>
            <ul id="navul01">
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#news">blog</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav></div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="space">
            <li><a></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="subjects_nav">
            <li><a id="physics_image" href="#home">PHYSICS</a></li>
            <li><a id="chemistry_image" href="pages\chemistry\chemistry.html">CHEMISTRY</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fixed, z-index and calculate the postion using top and not bottom. The value should be the height of the header minus the height of the navbar:

*run the snippet full width as it won't work on the reduced size since the header is big*

```css
header {
    width:100%; 
    height:350px; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:-1;
    border:3px solid grey;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
} 

#navul01 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 300px;
    z-index:999;
}

#navul01 li {
    float: left;
}

#navul01 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:2px solid white;
}

#navul01 li a:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}


#subjects_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

#subjects_nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:3px solid white;
    transition: 1s;
}

#subjects_nav li a:hover {
    margin: 0 -5%;
}

#physics_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

#chemistry_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

#maths_image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    background-image:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size: cover;
}

#space {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   </head>

   <body> 
      <div class="main-wrapper"> 
         <header> </header> 
         <div><nav>
            <ul id="navul01">
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#news">blog</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav></div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="space">
            <li><a></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul id="subjects_nav">
            <li><a id="physics_image" href="#home">PHYSICS</a></li>
            <li><a id="chemistry_image" href="pages\chemistry\chemistry.html">CHEMISTRY</a></li>
            <li><a id="maths_image" href="#contact">MATHS</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```